# image uploaded by android is empty to laravel

Tags: android, laravel

Android is uploading image from my laravel 5.7 API but the 
$request->input('image') is always on empty. I also try it using postman and its working fine. can someone help me out? XD

success result using post man form-data type

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) 
{
   $image = $request->file('image');
   $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/messenger');
   $image->move($destinationPath, $name);                                  
   $path = url('')."/webservices/public/uploads/messenger/".$name;

    $result=[
      "image_url"  => $path,
    ];  

    $succes = "1";
    $successMessage = "Image uploaded";
    $errorMessage = "";

}
else
{
    $result = (object) array();
    $succes = "0";
    $successMessage = "";
    $errorMessage = "Image not found";
}
```

Comment: Your saying $request->input('image') is empty?

Comment: To get an image you use $request->file('image'), which is what it looks like your doing.

Comment: ops im sorry im using  $request->file('image')

Comment: That's what your suppose to use for an image/file.

Comment: yeah i was using  $request->file('image') but that is the problem im always having empty image but i tested it using post man and its working fine

Comment: Ok, so you got it working now?

Comment: Thank you all for the reply and comments. android dev is doing what android usally do, he didnt set the correct send type.

Answer (score 0):

use Storage Facades for storing file :

create folder inside `storage/app/public/uploads/messenger` : with 777 permission

run command : `php artisan storage:link` to symlink your storage folder content available to public folder

in your controller :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Carbon\Carbon;


    public function upload_image(Request $request){ 
    try{
         // added validator for image field 

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:5120'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $response=array('status'=>'error','result'=>0,'errors'=>implode(',',$validator->errors()->all()));
            return response()->json($response, 200);
       }else{
           if($request->hasFile('image')){
             $uniqueid=uniqid();
             $original_name=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
             $size=$request->file('image')->getSize();
             $extension=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
             $filename=Carbon::now()->format('Ymd').'_'.$uniqueid.'.'.$extension;
             $imagepath=url('/storage/uploads/messenger/'.$filename);
             $path=$request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/messenger/',$filename);   

          $response=array('status'=>'success','result'=>1,'image'=>$imagepath);
          return response()->json($response, 200);
          }else{
          $response=array('status'=>'error','result'=>0,'errors'=>'no image found');
          return response()->json($response, 200);              
          }
       }
     }catch(\Exception $e){
        $response=array('status'=>'error','result'=>0,'errors'=>'Internal Server Error');
        return response()->json($response, 500);
    } 
  }
```

add `Content-Type : multipart/form-data` header when uploding image from client side like `android` or `postman`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Saurabh Mistry